# iOS Push Notification Action Button Doesn't Appear

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I'm trying to add action button for push notification. Actually, It is adding successfully when I build the app and give permission for notifications first time.

The problem begins after when I killed the app and trying to send notification again. Notification is receiving but action button doesn't appear. I think I don't define setNotificationCategories() method in right place but I can't find right solution for this issue. Here is my code: *(Thanks for any help)*

AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) {(granted, error) in
            if !granted {
                print("Notification access denied.")
            }
            setNotificationCategory()
        }

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            setNotificationCategory()
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        }

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        if response.notification.request.content.categoryIdentifier == Constants.Notification.Category.general{
            if response.actionIdentifier == Constants.Notification.Action.likeAction{
                if let notificationID = response.notification.request.content.userInfo["notification_id"]{
                    NotificationActionHandler.likeActionHandler(notificationID: notificationID as! Int)
                }
            }

        }

        completionHandler()
    }

    func setNotificationCategory(){
        let likeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: Constants.Notification.Action.likeAction, title: "❤️", options: [])
        let generalCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: Constants.Notification.Category.general, actions: [likeAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: .customDismissAction)
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.setNotificationCategories([generalCategory])
    }
}
```

NotificationActionHandler:

```
import Foundation

class NotificationActionHandler{

    class func likeActionHandler(notificationID: Int){
        print("liked! ❤️ \(notificationID)")
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. You are not defining the notification categories. Please refer to this. https://cocoacasts.com/actionable-notifications-with-the-user-notifications-framework

Comment: I've tried to implement that in a viewcontroller, but nothing changed. The  tutorial has focused to local notifications.

Comment: shat is the difference between local and remote notification in term of actions for the notification?

Comment: Yes, for example not necessary to define content.categoryIdentifier property for push. Actually, I have also local notifications with action buttons and it's working properly.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe your problem is that you are calling `setNotificationCategory` twice. Anytime that you call setNotificationCategory function it will override the previous settings that you have had on your app